# Is there an event like hashchange for query strings?

Tags: javascript, query-string

I have been using hashes to pass data between pages (like setting `scrollTop()`, etc.) and have also used the `hashChange` event to trigger changes on a given page.

However, hashes have default behaviors that I'm not necessarily interested in, like making the page jump to a given (sometimes insignificant) spot.

I feel like getting/setting a query string would be more logical, but:

1. Is it?
2. Is there an event I can listen for when the query string is set?
3. Are there query-string-related behaviors I should know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is illogical to reinvent anchor behaviour. It is better to not expose hash links to insignificant fragments (although modern browsers are doing `scrollIntoView()` for any element with `id`, there is a dedicated behaviour for `<a name="xxx">`). So, answer is yes here, page arguments should be passed via querystring.
2. Event is `window.beforeunload`, yes, page reload when `javascript:void(location.search='some')` has been *set*
3. There are no surprises, have a [look](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Properties)

Also, on working with querystring: http://xkr.us/js/querystring

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you're doing.

A query string change will always trigger a page reload. The only part of the URL you can change without a page reload is the #-part.

In javascript applications, page loads are generally not okay. But it may be possible to use when having a traditional html page request/response model.

There's no event AFAIK though, since it will change page.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer says, changing the query string will cause a page reload. As far as the browser is concerned you'll then be on a completely new page.

There are events that will fire when you do this. The ’beforeunload` event will fire, however it won't be very useful as it also fires when the user clicks on a link or closes the window.

Effectively the event that will fire if you change the query string will be the load event on the new page that it loads.